# How to merge and manipulate json?

Tags: java, json

My question is a bit complicated and I wasted whole day without any good effect

I get from one place a such Json:

```
{"vehicle":4,"year":2002}
```

from another String :

```
["productCode","PL","productCode","DE"]
```

I dont know how to convert it to key value object like:

```
"productCode": "PL"
```

because productCode duplicate I can not use hashmap :(

and a string:

```
"options":[]
```

I wish at the end I get json:

```
{
  "vehicle":4,
  "year":2002",
  "products":[
    {"productCode":"PL"},
    {"productCode":"DE"}
  ],
  "options":[]
}
```

Could someone help me please :)

Comment: Your structure does not make a lot of sense, "products":[{"productCode":"PL"},{"productCode":"DE"}] is a list of nested json with only one value? I think that you should change your format can be just a list of String and then you would be able to use maps because you don´t need to use the duplicated key productcode

Comment: but I need exactly this style: {"vehicle":4,"year":2002,","products":[{"productCode":"PL"},{"productCode":"DE"}],"options":[]}

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are going to encounter only `productCode` as a string in that list of elements, then remove it from the list and iterate over the remaining ones so that they can be added to a mutable list of maps. Later on, you can convert that `Map` to a JSON string using whichever library you have.

In another case, assuming only **keys** are going to get repeated in a list of strings, just take out the repetitive element, treat that as your key and repeat the above-mentioned method.

Rather than performing operation directly on the JSON string, I would say use dictionary/maps for manipulation, and at the end let your function return the final map and so that it can be converted into a JSON string.

Let me know if that helps.